# Is it possible to use Paypal’s Installment Plan with woocommerce?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

Is it possible to use Paypal’s Installment Plan (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/installment_buttons/) with Woocommerce?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using WooCommerce's Subscriptions plugin https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/.

It does work with PayPal, however you won't be using PayPal buttons, but use Woo's integrated installment plans you create with PayPal as a payment option at checkout.

1. Verifiable gateway link`https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/payment-gateways/?_ga=1.217520534.1256777508.1467905591`
2. Change Log for plugin; denotes
   installments`http://dzv365zjfbd8v.cloudfront.net/changelogs/woocommerce-subscriptions/changelog.txt`

Hope this helps 8^)

Comment: Thank you.. It is an expensive extention

Answer (score 0):

It also has a major flaw that isn't mentioned.

It can handle the automatic billing process of installment payments or subscriptions, but it will ask the customer each payment to have to manually log in and pay each time (so it isn't automatic or gives greater opportunity for them to cancel).  If you want it to automatically pay, you need 'reference transactions' enabled in your paypal account.  After 2 conversations with PayPal, they do not do this for new businesses or small turnover businesses, you have to be established with a big turnover.